# Azure Function SSH.Net Socket read operation has timed out

Tags: c#, azure, sftp, azure-functions

I'm attempting to connect from a timed Azure function to a 3rd party SFTP server that I have access to, but do not control.  My function runs successfully locally when using the azure functions emulator, however I receive an exception ("Socket read operation has timed out after 30000 milliseconds.") when attempting to run in Azure.

Is there anything from a networking perspective I need to do to allow/set up outbound SFTP connections, or does anyone see anything wrong with my code below?

```
var ftpHost = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SFTP:Server");
var ftpUser = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SFTP:User");
var ftpPass = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SFTP:Password");
var ftpDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SFTP:WorkingDirectory");

log.Info($"Connecting to {ftpHost}"); //This outputs the correct values I would expect from my app settings
using (var sftp = new SftpClient(ftpHost, ftpUser, ftpPass))
{
    sftp.Connect(); //This throws the exception
    log.Info("Connected");

    var files = sftp.ListDirectory(ftpDirectory);
    log.Info("Directory listing successful");

    var exceptions = new List<Exception>();
    foreach (var file in files.Where(f => f.IsRegularFile))
    {
        try
        {
            log.Info($"{file.FullName} - {file.LastWriteTimeUtc}");
            var records = Process(sftp, file);
            log.Info($"Parsed {records.Count} records");

            sftp.DeleteFile(file.FullName);
            log.Info($"Deleted {file.FullName}");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            exceptions.Add(ex);
        }
    }

    if (exceptions.Any())
    {
        throw new AggregateException(exceptions);
    }
}
```

**Edit**
I did leave my failing code out there and the failures appear to be intermittent.  Running every 15 minutes, I have a roughly 50% success rate.  In the last 20 attempts, 10 have succeeded.

Comment: it said, timeout, have you tried to increase the timeout ??

Comment: I have not - When successful (locally) the entire function runs in about 2 seconds, there's no reason the server connection should take 30+ seconds.

Comment: Not sure if the server side is blocking IPs from your Function App. There is a list of outbound IPs for your Function App (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/ip-addresses#find-outbound-ip-addresses) but I don't think that will help since you do not control the SFTP server. 

Your workflow does not seem very complicated. Logic Apps has built in SFTP support. Would that be an option for you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sftp

Comment: @LingToh I would rather not go the logic apps route as I'd like to keep all of my processes as part of the same code base (and I don't feel very confident it would have a different success rate).  I've also edited my post to include more long-term results and partial successes.

Comment: I'm having the same problem running a dotnet core 3.1 function app on the premium plan. Locally it runs just fine. It does not when deployed to Azure.